# how to detect specific edge from an image on html5 canvas and save image inside specific edge

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

How to detect specific edge from an image on HTML canvas and save image inside specific edge?
I have an image with 2 edges and I want to get second edged image separated in canvas along with first edge image in separate canvas.